# echo $USER print blank in ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to print the user name in a ubuntu docker but this print an empty space

echo "$USER"

is there anything I'm missing?
my ultimate goal is to create a new user and switch to it with docker command but I stock at the first step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a variable there. Try

```
whoami
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65213173/10946588) works. But if you still want to use the `USER` variable from docker, add this line into the dockerfile.

`RUN echo 'export USER=$(whoami)' >> /home/user/.bashrc`

It will set the `USER` variable in `.bashrc` with the value of `whoami`.